# When I trigger the send_message api of the ejabberd from post man it always returs 0 that is a positive response, why?

Tags: api, ejabberd

When I trigger the send_message api either the client is offline or online, the response from the api is 0 that means success. So the message is sent is what the response tells us right!.

But if the client is offline and if I trigger the send_message api now, the message will not be received by the client, then why is the api's response is showing 0- success. How can I get a response that the message is not sent since the user is offline, from the ejabberd

Answer (score 0):

> it always returs 0 that is a positive response, why?

Right, the result returned by that command is almost irrelevant.

That command returns as result what ejabberd_router:route returns. And that function always returns success, except when there is a problem building the stanza.

The stanza is sent, even if it's sent to an offline account, or to an account tha does not exist. If the stanza is sent to a remote server, how can we know he received it or not? That's not a problem of stanza routing... that's a problem of stanza reception akcnowledgment, and that command is not focused on that.

> How can I get a response that the message is not sent since the user is offline, from the ejabberd

If the destination account is local, and hosted by ejabberd, you can check if the account has some online session with positive priority. If the priority is negative, then the message is only delivered if you send it to the proper resource.

For example:

User is online with positive priority (zero is positive too):

```
$ ejabberdctl user_sessions_info admin localhost
c2s_tls ::ffff:127.0.0.1        33517   0      ejabberd@localhost      67      away    tka1

$ ejabberdctl send_message chat user@localhost admin@localhost "" HiZero1
$ ejabberdctl send_message chat user@localhost admin@localhost/tka1 "" HiZero2
```

User receives both messages.

If the account is online with negative priority:

```
$ ejabberdctl user_sessions_info admin localhost
c2s_tls ::ffff:127.0.0.1        33517   -2      ejabberd@localhost      67      away    tka1
```

This message will not be delivered:

```
$ ejabberdctl send_message chat user@localhost admin@localhost "" Hiii344
```

This message will be delivered, because it is sent to the specific resource (tka1):

```
$ ejabberdctl send_message chat user@localhost admin@localhost/tka1 "" Hiii344
```